# Does consoleblank turn off display?

Tags: linux, grub

Does `consoleblank` turn off display or does it set brightness to 0?

```
$ cat /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="consoleblank=600 quiet"
```

Answer (score 0):

The consoleblank kernel parameter sets the timeframe until the monitor gets disabled via [DPMS](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Battery-Powered/displaytypes.html).

It can be considered as "off"